# Роль денег в человеческом счастье. Или для счастья?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Недавно писал сочинение по русскому языку. В качестве проблемы, которую поднимает автор текста, я выбрал вопросительное предложение: "Какова роль денег **в** человеческом счастье?"
Учитель сказал, что правильно так: "Какова роль денег **для** человеческого счастья?".
Какой из вариантов верный?

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, *Пакетик Game*! P. S. Удивительное дело: три ответа на, казалось бы, *простущий* вопрос... И никто, кроме меня, его *положительно* не отметил. Эх-эх, непорядок это, думаю. Новичков надо поддерживать, лелеять...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова мне кажется, вопрос не совсем тривиальный, так как он касается особенностей русского, деньги в счастье - для меня криво. А в английском так пишут вполне себе, там вообще часто употреляют какова роль того/сего в том-то. А вы как считаете? И забыл лайкнуть, вы правы - поддержал.

Comment: Ах-ха! Деньги **в** счастье — криво. А деньги **для** счастья — ровно? (А вообще-то, у нас тут всё касается *особенностей* русского.) P. S. Изобразите, пожалуйста, какое-нибудь "человеческое" имечко для конкретного обращения к Вам.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Деньги для счастья - не очень, но в целом допустимо: сколько тебе денег для счастья нужно, или что тебе для счастья надо? То есть можно предмет для состояния. Но разместить предмет в состоянии нельзя. Какой ник вас устроит? Так лучше? Оборот "роль в" - это английский язык, по-русски так я бы воздержался говорить, без необходимости, потому что играть роль - это специфическое выражение.

Comment: *Буратино* после *άνθρωπος* — хорошо! Спасибо.

Comment: @Буратино Славно-славно и каламбурно вы меня подловили с ником. Как дура (нет — чтобы посмотреть перевод), попросила *какое-нибудь "человеческое" имечко*... Развожу руками... Кланяюсь...

Answer (score 2):

Счастье (здесь) — чувство, ощущение, состояние, а не событие, а не что-то конкретное, не предмет "счастье". *Для счастья* — устойчивое выражение. *В счастье, в радости* говорят, когда пишут про нахождение в состоянии: "Они жили в счастье и в радости". И вот, например, "каково значение денег в любви" — как будто у вас любовь с деньгами, предметами).

*Роль А в ощущении Б* звучит криво. *Роль А для ощущения Б* — лучше, но я бы подумал еще над словом "роль", потому что роль в "действии/событии", а не в состоянии. Роль в состоянии может играть другое состояние, например, "какую роль в счастье играет вера".

Как сильно важны деньги для человеческого счастья?

Как сильно человеческое счастье зависит от денег?

Ну и — *нет в деньгах счастья* (возможно, для употребления, потому что подчинение наоборот), но счастья из денег не получить, деньги это просто бумажки с цифрами.

Comment: Не буду растекаться... Чисто за философичность (я так не умею!) — *пли-у-юз*...

Answer (score 1):

Если вас, как носителя языка, поправляют по вопросам грамматики, то крайне маловероятно, что они правы. Слово ‟роль” в таком значении определённо допустимо использовать с предлогом ‟в” – роль в жизни дочери, его роль в победе, роль в неудачах. Подобные поправления являются следствием грамматического невроза, который часто встречается среди лингвистов, когда им мерещатся грамматические ошибки на каждом шагу.

Comment: «В качестве проблемы, которую поднимает автор текста, я выбрал вопросительное предложение», — так написано в вопросе. Уверены, что писал носитель, и его не надо поправлять?

Comment: Я уверен, что в этом предложении нет абсолютно никаких именно грамматических ошибок.

Comment: Предложение может быть абсолютным бредом, но не иметь грамматических ошибок – Сталь пригласила космос на свадьбу лужайки.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, если придираться, можно, например, так обосновывать:

```
Значимость денег в человеческом счастье // явный бред
Значимость денег для человеческого счастья // ок
```

Но в целом я согласен с предыдущим оратором, используйте любые слова, которые явно не режут слух.